# Рефлексия. Constructor.newInstance(params)

Tags: java, рефлексия

Задача: имею имя класса. С помощью рефлексии достаю из него все доступные конструкторы и предлагаю пользователю выбрать какой-то. После того как он выбрал, он вводит желаемые параметры определённого конструктора и создается объект по этому к-у. 
Вопрос: как в Constructor.newInstance(params) на место params засунуть всё то, что хочет задать пользователь? Например, у меня есть конструктор с полями (int, String), как сделать объект по этому к-у?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [докам](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29), в качестве params надо передавать Object[] с вашими аргументами. Т.е. при конструкторе вида

> (int, String)

надо как-то так:

```
Integer firstArg=42;
String secondArg="Ответ на сей вопрос я нагуглил за 20 секунд!";
Object[] args=new Object[]{firstArg, secondArg);
Constructor.newInstance(args);
```

Причём передавать в метод надо именно не примитивы, а их обертки-объекты.

---

В общем случае, согласно [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection) делается так:

1) Получаем массив конструкторов.

2) Методом

```
getParameterTypes()
```

Получаем массив типов аргументов конструктора.

3) Создаём массив переменных узнанных типов и создаём объект как описано выше.

Comment: Вы нагуглили примитив. А если у меня 3 аргумента, или меньше, или больше?

Comment: @111xbot111, почему не то? Просто немного ошибся. Надо да, массив Object-ов предавать, а не отдельные аргументы. Ответ исправил.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не в том дело. Вернее, не только в том. Ну, вот например: у вас в классе есть 3 к-а: (int), (long, String, double), (boolean, int, int). Сперва пользователь хочет создать объект по первому к-у,  а потом захочет по 3. В этом случае мы не можем привязаться ни к заранее определённым типам переменных (как у Вас написано Integer firstArg; String secondArg;), ни к их кол-ву (а вдруг не два, а три, не три, а один, и так далее)

Comment: Мне нужно решить не приведенный пример, а общий случай, если так можно сказать.

Comment: @111xbot111, должен признать, что я не очень понял, в чём проблема. В том, что вы не можете получить список типов (классов) аргументов конструктора?

Comment: @111xbot111, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо, это уже ближе. Я достал список типов, а потом предлагаю пользователю ввести это все с клавиатуры - он вводит, и я имею список значений (в string) того, что он там навводил. Проблема в том, что мне нужно создать массив классов, а этим классам присвоить значения, которые ввел пользователь. Вот тут не очень понимаю, что делать. Ну, а потом просто сей массив закинуть в newInstance()

Comment: @111xbot111, таки это же не сложно... Ввёл юзверь строки, а вы их приведите к нужным и заранее известным типам. Типа 

    Integer integer=Integer.parseInt("111");
    Boolean boolean1 = Boolean.valueOf("true");

и т.д. Это-то нагуглить не сложно по запросам типа: "тип" convert to "тип".

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаем массив типа класс.
2. Считываем ввод пользователя.
3. Узнаем тип, запихиваем в массив.
4. Повторяем 2-3, если нужно.
5. Массив передаем в качестве параметра в `.newInstance()`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, там уже не лезут комменты. Да, конвертация это вообще не вопрос. Я понял, что делать так: 1) получаю стринг 2)if int/float/... {конвертация} 3) добавляю новосозданный объект в массив 4) повторяю сколько нужно 5) засовываю в ньюИнстанс. Вопрос: как можно сократить 2-ой ход, а то больно много ифов будет, если делать проверку для каждого типа.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @111xbot111, ну, проще, думаю, через оператор **swich** пропустить. Будет красивее и меньше кода. Либо извратиться и чрез ту же рефлексию создавать объекты **Integer**, **Boolean** и т.д. и у них вызывать 

    valueOf("пользовательский ввод");

Но я не уверен, что у всех типов такой метод есть и верно отработает. Так что я бы чрез **swich** сделал бы.